# Why geometric median cannot be solved analytically

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

$\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}$
For a given set of $m$ points $x_1,...,x_m$ with each $x_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$, the geometric median (or the weber point) is defined as $$\argmin\limits_{y \in \mathbb{R^n}} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \|x_i-y \|_2 $$
I am asking for an explanation for why this optimization problem cannot be solved analytically. Also, I am asking for a explanation about how to solve it numerically.

Comment: What have you tried so far? For instance, what conditions must $y$ satisfy to minimize the total squared deviations?

Comment: I have answered a related question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401128/how-can-i-find-an-optimal-point-on-a-scatter-graph/1401262#1401262

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking the question "why this optimization problem cannot be solved analytically" seems to me problematic. For one thing, I'm unaware if anyone has even attempted to *prove* that a problem of this form cannot be solved analytically. [EDIT: I am now! See Semiclassical's link in the comment below; it does happen to be proven in this particular case that no analytic solution exists for $m\geq 5$.] But that seems like a rather odd thing to attempt to prove anyway. Rather, it ought to satisfy you simply that *we don't know how* to solve it analytically. If you or someone else discovers a way, great! Publish it! But short of that, asking "why" seems akin to confusing an absence of evidence with evidence of absence.

Furthermore, it really should not be surprising that any given optimization model fails to admit an analytic solution. Problems that do are the *exception*; and if you find one, you had better not want to change it *in any way* lest you break that precious property. For example, we can solve a pure least squares problem by solving a single linear system in $O(n^3)$ operations. But the minute we add nearly *any* complicating factor---for example, selecting a different norm than the $\ell_2$ norm, adding an $\ell_1$ regularizer, bounds on the variables, etc.---we can no longer rely on our analytic approach.

As for the problem itself, it is a rather simple form of a [second-order-cone program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming). A variety of solvers out there can handle such a problem reliably. If you're willing to use MATLAB, my software [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx) make specifying the problem simple. If we assume that the vectors $x_i$ are stacked into an $n\times m$ matrix `X`, the model is simply

```
cvx_begin
    variable y(n)
    minimize(sum(norms(X-y(:,ones(1,m))))
cvx_end
```

Comment: With regards to it whether it can be analytically constructed: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/881144/137524

Comment: Very cool! Please consider offering this as an answer.