# Minimizing a function of a complex variable

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers, convex-optimization

> Given complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3,\ldots,z_n \in \mathbb{C}.$ Does
>   there exist a $z \in \mathbb{C}$, for which the function  $$f(z) =
>  \sum_{j=1}^n |z-z_j|$$ achieves a global minimum? If yes, then find
>   $z$.

Not sure how to approach this problem. Any advice?

Comment: This is not really a complex analysis question, since you only use properties of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Is this homework?

Comment: $f$ is continuous. Hence it attains a minimum on every nonempty compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. What other property of $f$ then guarantees the existence of a global minimum?

Comment: I'm not convince this should really be called a problem on complex numbers, as opposed to mere points in the plane.  The difference is the way in which complex numbers are multiplied.

Comment: I think I once solved the problem of finding the minimum value of the sum when $n=3$, by hand.  It's doable but moderately onerous. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to the [geometric median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) problem in $\mathbb{R}^2$. That is: for each $z_j$, define
$$\bar{z}_j \triangleq \begin{bmatrix} \Re z_j \\ \Im z_j \end{bmatrix}$$
Then the geometric median is the solution of
$$\bar{z}=\arg\min \sum_{i=1}^n \|z-\bar{z}_j\|_2.$$
To recover your answer, $z=\bar{z}_1+j\bar{z}_2$. Note that if we were minimizing the sum of *squared* distances/magnitudes, the simple mean $z=n^{-1}\sum_j z_j$ would be the answer.

According to [this article](http://www.pnas.org/content/97/4/1423.full.pdf+html), when the points are not collinear, the geometric median is unique. When all of the points lie on a straight line, the minimum is achieved at any one-dimensional median, which may not be unique.

There is no closed-form solution for arbitrary $n$. However, it's a simple convex optimization problem, so a variety of approaches can be applied to it. For example, with my Matlab toolbox [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx) it can be expressed thusly, assuming the complex values $z_j$ are stored in the vector `z_in`:

```
cvx_begin
    variable z complex
    minimize(sum(abs(z-z_in))
cvx_end
```

CVX effectively makes use of the $\mathbb{R}^2$ mapping above, and converts the model to a [second-order cone program (SOCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming). The equivalent 
SOCP standard form is
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & \textstyle \sum_j y_j \\
\text{subject to} & \| \bar{z} - \bar{z}_j \| \leq y_j, ~ j=1,2,\dots,n
\end{array}$$
where the variables are $\bar{z}\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\bar{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and
the values $\bar{z}_j$ are defined above. There are plenty of solvers out there that can handle SOCP, so there's no need to use CVX if you don't want to.

Wikipedia describes Weiszfeld's algorithm, and claims it converges almost always. Expressed in this complex form, we have

$$z^{(i+1)} = \frac{ \sum_j z_j / | z_j - z^{(i)} | }{ \sum_j 1 / | z_j - z^{(i)} |}$$
The article claims that difficulties arise if the initial iterate (or presumably any others) coincides exactly with one of the points. It seems to me that the geometric mean would be a good initial point in practice, save this one caution.

Comment: Thanks for the LaTeX tune-up @Michael Hardy!

Comment: Im not really familiar with convex optimization - I was hoping we could perhaps derive a closed form for $z$ in terms of the $z_j$'s ? Also I noticed that for n=3 $z$ is the Fermat-Point - well that seems to be a special case of the Geometric Median concept - which you have pointed out. Also, can a given set of points in Euclidean Space have more than 1 geometric medians ?

Comment: "There is no closed form solution for arbitrary n>3" - Is there a formal argument for this ? Wikipedia states " it has been shown that no explicit formula, nor an exact algorithm involving only arithmetic operations and kth roots can exist in general." - but without references .

Comment: There are plenty of references in the Wikipedia article; consider studying them. I've edited my post to link to one making the collinearity claim above.

Comment: Also, this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881144/is-the-non-existence-of-a-general-quintic-formula-related-to-the-impossibility-o Looks I was wrong about $n>3$; there is a formula for $n=4$, but not $n\geq 5$.